# Custom Workflow shows Error on Passing Parameters

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-365

Dynamics CRM 365

In Custom Action Add a step of CustomWorkflow
without Parameters CustomWorkflow Execute successfully
but with parameters shows Error
" System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred."

```
    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        ITracingService _tracer = context.GetExtension<ITracingService>();
        IWorkflowContext _workflowContext = context.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
        IOrganizationServiceFactory _serviceFactory = context.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
        IOrganizationService _service = _serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(_workflowContext.UserId);
        try
        {
            string _emailId = EmailID.Get<string>(context);
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("An Error Occured" + _emailId);
        }
        catch (FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault> ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("An Error Occured in Followup Plugin!", ex);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            _tracer.Trace("Exception", ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }

    [Input("EmailID")]
    public InArgument<string> EmailID { get; set; }
    [Input("SubPoId")]
    public InArgument<string> SubPOId { get; set; }
```

Comment: throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("An Error Occured" + _emailId);
should use for emailId passed or not for checking parameters
without this line also shows Error

Comment: Why are you throwing an `InvalidPluginExecutionException` within the `try` block?

Comment: Just for testing without it shows same error

Answer (score 0):

What if you remove `<string>` so your line reads:

```
string _emailId = EmailID.Get(context);
```